# Summing cost by id that appears on multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

**SOLUTION**

I solved it by simple doing the following.

```
SELECT table_size, sum(cost) as total_cost, sum(num_players) as num_players
FROM
(
  SELECT table_size, cost, sum(tp.uid) as num_players
  FROM tournament as t
  LEFT JOIN takes_part AS tp ON tp.tid = t.tid
  LEFT JOIN users as u on u.uid = tp.tid
  JOIN attributes as a on a.aid = t.attrId
  GROUP BY t.tid
) as res
GROUP BY table_size
```

I wasn't sure it would work, what with the other aggregate functions that I had to use in my real sql, but it seems to be working ok. There may be problems in the future if I want to do other kind of calculations, for instance do a COUNT(DISTINCT tp.uid) over all tournaments. Still, in this case that is not all that important so I am satisfied for now. Thank you all for your help.

**UPDATE!!!**
Here is a Fiddle that explains the problem:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e03ff/7

I want to get:

```
table_size  |  cost
-------------------------------
5           |  110
8           |   80
```

**OLD POST**

I'm sure that there is an easy solution to this that I'm just not seeing, but I can't seem to find a solution to it anywhere. What I'm trying to do is the following:

I need to sum 'costs' per tournament in a system. For other reasons, I've had to join with lots of other tables, making the same cost appear on multiple rows, like so:

```
id | name | cost | (hidden_id)
-----------------------------
0  | Abc  | 100  | 1
1  | ASD  | 100  | 1
2  | Das  | 100  | 1
3  | Ads  |  50  | 2
4  | Ads  |  50  | 2
5  | Fsd  |   0  | 3
6  | Ads  |   0  | 3
7  | Dsa  |   0  | 3
```

The costs in the table above are linked to an id value that is not necessary selected in by the SQL (this depends on what the user decides at runtime). What I want to get, is the sum 100+50+0 = 150. Of course, if I just use SUM(cost) I will get a different answer. I tried using SUM(cost)/COUNT(*)*COUNT(tourney_ids) but this only gives correct result under certain circumstances. A (very) simple form of query looks like this:

```
SELECT SUM(cost) as tot_cost -- This will not work as it sums all rows where the sum appears.
FROM t
JOIN ta ON t.attr_id = ta.toaid
JOIN tr ON tr.toid = t.toid  -- This row will cause multiple rows with same cost
GROUP BY *selected by user*  -- This row enables the user to group by several attributes, such as weekday, hour or ids of different kinds.
```

UPDATE. A more correct SQL-query, perhaps:

```
SELECT
*some way to sum cost*
FROM tournament AS t
JOIN attribute AS ta ON t.attr_id = ta.toaid
JOIN registration AS tr ON tr.tourneyId = t.tourneyId
INNER JOIN pokerstuff as ga ON ta.game_attr_id = ga.gameId
LEFT JOIN people AS p ON p.userId = tr.userId
LEFT JOIN parttaking AS jlt ON (jlt.tourneyId = t.tourneyId AND tr.userId = jlt.userId)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t.tourneyId,
    ta.a - (ta.b) - sum(c)*ta.cost AS cost
    FROM tournament as t
    JOIN attribute as ta ON (t.attr_id = ta.toaid)
    JOIN registration tr ON (tr.tourneyId = t.tourneyId)
    GROUP BY t.tourneyId, ta.b, ta.a
) as o on t.tourneyId = o.tourneyId
AND whereConditions
GROUP BY groupBySql
```

**Description of the tables**

- tournament  (tourneyId, name, attributeId)
- attributes  (attributeId,  ..., gameid)
- registration (userId, tourneyId, ...)
- pokerstuff(gameid,...)
- people(userId,...)
- parttaking(userId, tourneyId,...)

Let's assume that we have the following (cost is actually calculated in a subquery, but since it's tied to tournament, I will treat it as an attribute here):

tournament:

```
tourneyId | name         | cost
1         | MyTournament |  50
2         | MyTournament |  80
```

and

```
userId | tourneyId
1      | 1
2      | 1
3      | 1
4      | 1
1      | 2
4      | 2
```

The problem is rather simple. I need to be able to get the sum of the costs of the tournaments without counting a tournament more than once. The sum (and all other aggregates) will be dynamically grouped by the user.

A big problem is that many solutions that I've tried (such as SUM OVER...) would require that I group by certain attributes, and that I cannot do. The group by-clause must be completely decided by the user. The sum of the cost should sum over any group-by attributes, the only problem is of course the multiple rows in which the sum appears.

Do anyone of you have any good hints on what can be done?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Is cost on table t - if not, which table? Is hidden_id on table t - if not, which table? Can you include the rest of your existing query?

Comment: Daniel - I ues PostgreSQL.

Comment: Mark. Cost is not on table t, no. It's from a subquery that calculates the cost in a complex way. But it is calculated per t (tourney), yes. The query is rather extensive and highly dynamic so it is a bit difficult to include it all.

Comment: Do you want to include a separate row at the end to hold the total cost (allowing for the fact that each given tournament's values may be appearing multiple times), do you want to include a fractional value of cost on each line such that the total of all those values adds up to the total cost (making the same allowances), or do you want the first row for a given tournament to return the full cost for that tournament with each subsequent row for the same tournament showing a cost of 0?

Comment: I don't want special rows for the sums. I just want to be able to group the cost by arbitrary attributes. See the fiddle example I just posted. For instance, I may want to group the cost by table size to be able to see how much the total cost of tournaments are if they have a certain table size.

Comment: Your fiddle uses MySQL, but you have tagged this question as PostgreSQL - which are you using? See this fiddle for an example that uses the approach outlined in my (updated) answer with the data from your fiddle, in PostgreSQL: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/e03ff/3

Comment: I am using postgresql but when I tried to use it Fiddle the whole thing froze. I seem to have found a solution actually, that doesn't require any partitioning at all. I will write it in here once I am 100% sure it works the way I want it to.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. There's no need to add tags to your titles, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190 for more information. Also, "Thanks" are implicit since you asked the question, and on Stackoverflow it's generally not needed, for us the question is the interesting part. You can put all text like that in your about page instead, it's always linked via your user card at the bottom right of each question and answer you provide on the site.

Comment: -1 This solution won't work in PostgreSQL at all, since the inner select statement includes fields that are neither grouped nor aggregated in a query that is grouped. Not only that, but you are SUMming the user IDs when you should probably be counting them. Also, although this query will run in MySQL, the output will be misleading if you try to group by an attribute that has multiple values for a given tournament ID, since such attributes will essentially be selected at random as part of the grouping, in the inner query.

Comment: Finally, a solution should be added as a new answer, not as an amendment to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
select *selected by user*, sum(case rownum when 1 then a.cost end)
from
(
    select
        *selected by user*, cost,
        row_number() over (partition by t.tid) as rownum
    FROM t
    JOIN ta ON t.attr_id = ta.toaid
    JOIN tr ON tr.toid = t.toid
) a
group by *selected by user*
```

The row_number is used to number each row with the same tournament row. When suming the costs we only consider those rows with a rownum of 1. All other rows are duplicates of this one with regards to the costs.

---

In terms of the fiddle:

```
select table_size, sum(case rownum when 1 then a.cost end)
from
(
  SELECT
      table_size, cost,
      row_number() over (partition by t.tid) as rownum
  FROM tournament as t
  LEFT JOIN takes_part AS tp ON tp.tid = t.tid
  LEFT JOIN users as u on u.uid = tp.tid
  JOIN attributes as a on a.aid = t.attrId
) a
group by table_size
```

Comment: I get a "aggregate function calls cannot contain window function calls". Also, I know that PostgreSQL does not support nestled aggregates.

Also, removing the nested clause I get "column 'cost must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function".

Comment: It's the join with tr that makes things incorrect so no, that won't work either. It is possible that one could do it with two subqueries but I was hoping to avoid that somehow.

Comment: @user2135776: What's the problem with `tr`? It would be good if you could provide some sample data in an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Well, in your case it's not necessarily the tr table that is the problem. That table contains the registrations of individual players for every tournament, and so of course when joining with that table we get lots of duplicates for everything in table t (tournament). The problem with the query you provided is that it messes things up for the other aggregates that I do (such as count the number of tournaments and the number of players, etc.). These need the information in the "lower" tables, t, tr, ta, and so on.

Comment: If I place the aggregates in the inner select, they cannot be selected in the outer select without being included in the group by. And if they are placed in the outer select they do not have access to the tables in the inner select.

Comment: @user2135776: You really should provide a fiddle.

Comment: I cannot provide all information about the tables because they are rather extensive. However, I will write a bit more about the individual tables.

Comment: @user2135776: Just provide a fiddle with sample data that illustrates the problem. I don't really care for your actual data or tables.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by fiddle. I can only find references to SQL Fiddle which doesn't quite fit in here. I'm assuming you mean something like sample data. I will try to write down a simplified problem.

Comment: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) (as already linked in a previous comment of mine) is exactly what I mean. It allows you to create a schema with sample data and execute queries on it. Example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/1

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm afraid I don't have the opportunity to do this at the moment. I will have to find out a solution some other way. I appreciate your help!

Comment: I have now had time to create a Fiddle that illustrates my problem. I updated the post now. Just in case anyone is still reading this post. :)

Answer (score 0):

As the repeated costs are the same each time you can average them by their hidden id and do something like this:

```
WITH MrTable AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT hidden_id, AVG(cost) OVER (PARTITION BY hidden_id) AS cost
  FROM stuff
)
SELECT SUM(cost) FROM MrTable;
```

Comment: The problem here is the same as the one I mentioned in Mark Bannister's reply. The hidden_id (the tourneyId) cannot be used in the partition-by clause without being used in the group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

(Updated) Given that the cost currently returned is the total cost per tournament, you could include a fractional value of cost on each line of an inner select, such that the total of all those values adds up to the total cost (allowing for the fact that each given tournament's values may be appearing multiple times), then sum that fractional cost in your outer select, like so:

```
select table_size, sum(frac_cost) as agg_cost from
(SELECT a.table_size , cost / count(*) over (partition by t.tid) as frac_cost
 FROM tournament as t
 LEFT JOIN takes_part AS tp ON tp.tid = t.tid
 LEFT JOIN users as u on u.uid = tp.uid
 JOIN attributes as a on a.aid = t.attrId) sq
GROUP BY table_size
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/e03ff/15).

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work since the tourneyId cannot be used in the "partition by" clause without being included in the group by clause. That is unfortunately the main problem.

Comment: @user2135776: I see your point - I have updated my answer to allow for it.